# How to get a specific tag from xml document which is in xml format too using php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get specific tags from myxmlfile, and I want those tags to be in an xml format.
Here is the code  that i have tried so far but am still missing something.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('MyXmlFile.xml');

$result = $xml->xpath('/Batch/Commands/Command');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo $node->asXML('two.xml');
}
```

Comment: instead of echo replace from this code and check, var_dump($node->asXml());

Comment: The problem here is not var_dumping or echoing, The problem is to get the command tag which is in myxmlfile.xml file.

Comment: I want to know the result when dumping, can you post it, the result of echo?

Comment: Maybe your selector is empty, check content of `$result` using `var_dump`

Comment: Okay, var_dump does not return anything.

Comment: And I think its because simplexml_load_file() does not work well with xpath.

Comment: not it's working with xpath, you should give the right path and echo $node->asXml(); , dont pass any parameters to asXml function.

Comment: Please add a small example of you XML to the question. That way we can see if the Xpath should work. (Maybe it uses a namespace.)